# Get the value of entered by the user in the class property

Tags: asp.net

I have the class defined as below

```
public partial class School
{
 public StudentDetails StudentDetails;
 private List<string> studentcount;
    public List<string> StudentCount
    {
        get { return studentcount; }
        set { studentcount= value; }
    }
}
public enum StudentDetails
{
    Male,
    Female,
}
```

In my code, I have

```
   if (ctl.Contains("StudentDetails "))
   {
    ctrlStr = ctl.ToString();
    School.StudentDetails = (Request.Form[ctrlStr]);
   }
```

error above is cannot convert string to School.StudentDetails

```
 if(ctl.Contains("StudentCount"))
    {
     School.StudentCount=(Request.Form[ctrlStr]);
    }


   error here is cannot convert string to List<string>
```

Can you help me with the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
School.StudentDetails =  Enum.Parse(typeof(StudentDetails), Request.Form[ctrlStr])
```

for the first error.

Regarding the second one, why is student count a list of string?

Comment: @Janet had a typo. Can you try this?

Comment: @Janet why not just `int studentCount`

Comment: I have got the second one corrected by changing it to int, can you please help me with the first error.

Comment: was able to get the value with School.StudentDetails =(StudentDetails)Enum.Parse(typeof(StudentDetails), Request.Form[ctrlStr]);